# Jira attach file to issue with PHP and CURL

Tags: php, curl, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I have found several examples on how to upload an attachment to an issue in jira, however I have not been able to make any of them work. I posted this question on the Jira Community Help Forums but it has been over a week with 0 replies so hoping the community here can help.

Here is my current attempt:

```
 $Jirausername = 'myUsername';
    $Jirapassword = 'myPassword';

    $ch=curl_init();
$headers = array(
    'X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck',
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
);
$data = array('file' => "testing.txt");


curl_setopt_array(
    $ch,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL=>'https://myCompany.net/rest/api/latest/issue/TAG-78/attachments',
        CURLOPT_POST=>true,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$data,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=> 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER=>false,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> $headers,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD=>"$Jirausername:$Jirapassword"
    )
);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$ch_error = curl_error($ch);
if ($ch_error) {
    echo "cURL Error: $ch_error";
} else {
    var_dump($result);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

testing.txt is in the same directory as this file. I have curl installed on the webserver where this is hosted, can create issues in jira fine, just cant seem to upload attahcments...

When I run this page it displays:

```
string(0) ""
```

No attachment is uploaded as well needless to say. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Adding a bounty, here are some things I have tried:

1. trying both nocheck and no-check
2. trying both @testing.txt and testing.txt
3. removing 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
4. Full paths as such: `$data = array('file'=>"@C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\testing.txt ,'filename'=>'testing.txt');`
5. Tried like this too because of a known curl error: `$data = array('file'=>"@C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\testing.txt" ';filename=testing.txt');`

And every combination of those above. No matter what I try it does not work though. Have also ensured I am an admin level user in Jira. I feel like my code should work... but clearly not.

Comment: Can you try renaming `file` to `file_contents`: `$data = array('file_contents' => "testing.txt");`?

Comment: @grundic Done. Output changed to : string(2) "[]"                                    still no file uploaded .

Comment: [Here is](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-attach-an-attachment-in-a-jira-issue-using-rest-api-699957734.html) an example of standard cUrl, but I haven't find any difference so far.. Ah, `multipart/form-data` is not in Atlassian's example.

Comment: @grundic have also tried: `$headers = array(
    'X-Atlassian-Token: no-check'
);` With no luck. I found the standard curl example, as well as many other php examples: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-upload-file-and-then-attach-it-to-confluence-page-with/qaq-p/551467 however I just cant get mine to work. Did look around quite a bit for last week or so already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial assumption was wrong: it works with both *no-check* and *nocheck* -- it doesn't matter.

Instead of putting a file name as a parameter for `file`, you have first create a curl file object like this:

```
$cfile = curl_file_create('testing.txt');
```

And then put it into array:

```
$data = array('file' => $cfile);
```

Here is the full solution, which worked for me:

```
<?php
 $Jirausername = '<username>';
 $Jirapassword = '<password>';

$ch=curl_init();
$headers = array(
    'X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck',
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
);


$cfile = curl_file_create('testing.txt');
$data = array('file' => $cfile);


curl_setopt_array(
    $ch,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL=>'https://<JIRA-SERVER>/rest/api/latest/issue/<ISSUE-KEY>/attachments',
        CURLOPT_POST=>true,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$data,
        CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => 5,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=> 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER=>true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> $headers,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD=>"$Jirausername:$Jirapassword"
    )
);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$ch_error = curl_error($ch);
if ($ch_error) {
    echo "cURL Error: $ch_error";
} else {
    var_dump($result);
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: No difference. Both no-check and nocheck do nothing. Had tried both before.

Comment: It definitely must be `no-check`. It might be something else then.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. It has been a real pain in my side. Have tried putting the @ sign infront of testing.txt for both no-check and nocheck as well. Just since I didnt mention that in my post.

Comment: @Lain, please have a look at edited post, I was able to attach file using this approach.

Comment: Is my testing.txt in the wrong place somehow? When I run this it gives me: cURL Error: couldn't open file "testing.txt" . testing.txt is in the same directory as this php file though, seems odd to me it wouldnt be able to open it. Any ideas?

Comment: Worked, needed full path. Just need to rename it now since it upload the full path as the name of the file on jira. I think I have seen other posts on how to do that though. Gave you bounty, thanks

Comment: @grundic it worked perfectly. Thanks for sharing the code.